# How to remove whitespaces when we create XML

Tags: xml, scala, whitespace

Given the following code:

```
def createXmlOutput(...) : Elem =
{
   <something>
     { if (condition == true) <child>{ "my child value if condition would be true" }</child> }
     <otherchild>{ "my other child value" }</otherchild>
   </something>
}
```

I will get the following output in case the condition is false:

```
<something>

  <otherchild>my other child value</otherchild>
</something>
```

So, the `{ if.. }` block leads to an extra blank line in case the condition is false and the element is not placed.

How can I avoid this? I am building a rather large XML with lots of optional elements, which leads to excess whitespace and empty lines when doing it this way.

Is there a way to completely collapse whitespace & newlines after creating the XML, so I have it all in one line? (which would be my preferred style anyway, because its for machine-to-machine communication)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you have to add children manually is one way and another way is to use `scala.xml.Utility.trim`.
I have taken your code and re-written like this :

```
 def createXmlOutput(condition:Boolean) : Elem =
 {
   val parent: Elem = <something>
                      <otherchild>{ "my other child value" }</otherchild>
                      </something>
  val child = <child>{ "my child value if condition would be true" }</child>
  if(condition == true) parent.copy(child = parent.child :+ child)
   else parent
 }
```

Hope this helps

And also you can use something like this `scala.xml.Utility.trim(createXmlOutput(true))` if you are not adding the child manually.

Comment: Thanks, `scala.xml.Utility.trim(createXmlOutput(true))` did the trick.

Comment: yeah, that also make sense.

Comment: I have to add that using the same function (`scala.xml.Utility.trim`) also gets rid of any `#PCDATA` elements which are obstructive when iterating freshly parsed XML.